# Python Modules For Simple Exponential Calculation

Tags: python, python-2.7, module

I have a simple Python Program I'm working on and I'm new to programming and things aren't working too well.  I'm still learning Modules and Functions, but here are the program requirements.  I'm having trouble understanding the import and calling parts as well as Module argument parameters for the program as well as Global and Local Variables.  I'm still learning so any feedback or suggestions would be helpful. My book seems to be written in mostly Pseudocode and not actual Python code and it is making things confusing.

```
''' 
Write a program that has thee modules:

1) the first module takes two numbers from the user

2) the second module calculate firstNumber to the power of secondNumber and prints it

3) the third module will print 'end of program'
'''

Module main()
    #Global Variables 
    Declare Integer num1
    Declare Integer num2
    #Welcome Exponent Power Program 
    Print ('Welcome to the Exponent Powers Program.')
    Call askNumbers(num1, num2)
    Call numberPower
    Call endProgram
End Module   

#This program gets the 2 numbers from the user
Module askNumbers(Integer num1, Integer num2)
    num1 = int(raw_input('Enter Number : '))
    num2 = int(raw_input('Enter Raised Power Number: '))
End Module

Module numberPower(int num1, int num2)
    Declare Int expTotal 
    Set expTotal = (num1**num2)
    Print(expTotal)
End Module

Module endProgram()
    Print('End of Program')
End Module
```

Great help and thanks again for your time.

Comment: this is VisualBasic ... why are you using a VBA book in a python course? that is strange

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Each module is going to be a separate `.py` file. 
When you call `import <module name>` it will run through the module from top to bottom, adding all the definitions of functions/parameters that are present, and run any code if it is the first import

If I have a module:

**foo.py**

```
print "foo"
```

when I import foo, there is an action to be performed, so you will see

**idle**

```
>>> import foo
foo
>>>
```

If I put that in a function, nothing will print, however I will be able to use the function under the foo module name

**foo.py**

```
def foo():
    print "foo"
```

**idle**

```
>>> import foo
>>> foo.foo()
foo
# or using the from keyword I can get the function as just foo
>>> from foo import foo
>>> foo()
foo
```

If I want to call foo from another module say `bar.py`, I would do something like this

**bar.py**

```
from foo import foo
foo()
print "bar"
```

**idle**

```
>>>import bar
foo
bar
>>>
```

---

So In your case:

**module1.py**

```
a = int(raw_input("enter number 1: "))
b = int(raw_input("enter number 2: "))
```

**module2.py**

```
from module1 import a, b
print a**b
```

**module3.py**

```
import module2
print 'end of program'
```

**idle**

```
>>> import module3
enter number 1: 2
enter number 2: 3
8
end of program
>>>
```

Answer (score 0):

replace all `Module` with `def`

delete all `End Module`

add colon(`:`) to the end of each `def` line

delete all `Set`

change `Print` to `print`

delete the words `int` and `Integer`

anywhere it says `call some_module` replace with `some_module()`

delete any `Declare` lines

and I think then you have python

eg:

```
Module endProgram()
    Print('End of Program')
End Module
```

becomes

```
def endProgram():
    print "End of Program"
```

the reason it uses pseudocode(and Im not even sure thats pseudocode that looks like pascal or something(maybe vbasic)) is because  they are trying to teach you concepts not just how to copy and paste

a quick google search turns up that this is actually Visual Basic

Answer (score 0):

```
#This askNumber Module gets the 2 numbers from the user, and calls these 2
def askNumbers():
    print 'Welcome to Python Exponent Program'
    num1 = int(raw_input('Enter Number 1: '))
    num2 = int(raw_input('Enter Raised to Power Number 2: '))
    numberPower(num1, num2)

#This numberPower is the exponent calculation module   
def numberPower(num1, num2):
    expTotal = (num1**num2)
    print('Number 1 to the power of Number 2 is: ', expTotal)

#This module prints end Program    
def endProgram():
    print 'End of Program'

askNumbers() 
endProgram()   

#test 5^5: 3125
#test 3^4: 81
#test 7^6: 117649
#test 2^2: 4
```